# python coverage report lists things as files and not packages

Tags: python, code-coverage

When I run coverage report, I get something looking like this:

```
foo/
foo/bar/
foo/bar/baz
```

I was expecting something like:

```
foo
foo.bar
foo.bar.baz
```

This is a problem when I try to do `coverage xml` since everything gets lumped into a single nameless package.

Comment: Is there a programming question in there?  I will observe that if you glob the directories you can take the resulting strings and replace the / with a ..  You can also open all of the .py files and write some code to find all function and classes so you can get those appended.

Comment: I assume you're using [Ned Batchelder's coverage tool](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/)?

Comment: Yes, Ned Batchelder's coverage tool.

Comment: Using nose's built in --with-coverage somehow gets things in package form (instead of directory form) which is one step better.  Curious why I couldn't just do that with the coverage utility itself.